# How to split a server address and store in a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, split

I have a `List<string>` with some 10 strings.
The values are as follows:

```
\\Server\Site\MySite\File1.xml
\\Server\Site\MySite\File2.xml
\\Server\Site\MySite\File2.xml
.......................
\\Server\Site\MySite\File10.xml
```

I need to extract `\MySIte\File1.xml` to `\MySite\File10.xml` and store in another list.

I tried to use `Split` keyword, with another list to populate the splitted string. But it doesn't seem to give the correct answer.

Below is the code:

```
for(int index=0;index<list.Count;list++)
{
    string[] myArray=list[index].Split('\\');

    for(int innerIndex=0;innerIndex<myArray.Length;innerIndex++)
    {
        anotherList[innerIndex]=myArray[2]+"\\"+myArray[3];
    }
}
```

Experts please help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to work too hard if you know the input of all the strings

```
str.Substring(str.IndexOf("\\MySite"))
```

Comment: let me try your solution

Answer (score 0):

One word: LINQ!

```
var results = (from x in source
               let parts = x.Split('\\')
               select String.Join("\\", parts.Skip(1)).ToArray();
```

Comment: let me try your solution

Comment: List<string>=results.ToList(); gives me error if I try to bind the results from the LINQ query to a list. Please help

Comment: your LINQ query doesn't work.It gives me the original List again. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code.

```
        List<string> source = new List<string>();
        source.Add(@"\\Server\Site\MySite\File1.xml");
        source.Add(@"\\Server\Site\MySite\File2.xml");
        source.Add(@"\\Server\Site\MySite\File2.xml");
        source.Add(@"\\Server\Site\MySite\File10.xml");

        foreach(string s in source)
        {
            string[] parts = s.Split(new string[]{ Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString() },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Console.WriteLine(parts[parts.Length - 1] + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar +
                              parts[parts.Length - 2]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just remove anything before `\MySite` and get the rest:

Test data used:

```
List<string> source = new List<string>
{
    @"\\Server\Site\MySite\File1.xml",
    @"\\Server\Site\MySite\File2.xml",
    @"\\Server\Site\MySite\File2.xml",
    @"\\Server\Site\MySite\File10.xml",
};
```

query:

```
var result = 
    source
    // Start removing at 0 and remove everything before '\MySite'
    .Select(x => x.Remove(0, x.IndexOf("\\MySite")))
    .ToList();
```